# Get cyrillic result from base64.decode

Tags: android, base64, cyrillic

I have a database which is encoded with Base64. I am getting data from that DB and i use it in my android layouts. When there is Cyrillic encrypted text, all i am getting is a question mark in a rhombus. I am using standard function to decode and it is working properly with Latin characters.

```
public String decrypt(String text)
{
    String result;

    result = new String( Base64.decode( text, Base64.NO_WRAP ) );

    return result;
}
```

What should i change to get the Cyrillic output?

Comment: Try setting your character set when you encode and decode the strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to do:

```
result= new String( Base64.decode( text, Base64.DEFAULT ), "ISO-8859-5" );
```

Please change `ISO-8859-5` to suit your needs, but this should be standard cyrillic charset encoding.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was actually "Windows-1251" that i needed. I didn't checked that one earlier. Thanks :)